# ERD Diagram based on Crow's Foot model for Milky Way Jewelry

Tags: relational-theory, erd, database-diagrams, relations

this was on my final exam this past winter exam season, in search for the answer since i got it wrong:

> Draw an ERD diagram based on the Crow's Foot model for a database to support the basic operations of “Milky Way Jewelry”.

Specify:

- Entity sets, their attributes, and primary keys
- Relationship sets and their descriptive attributes (if such exist)
- Connectivities and cardinalities
- Decompose all M-M relationships, if any
- If found, replace any multivalued attributes and composite attributes

Each piece of jewelry for sale is assigned a `unique number`, and is described by the `name`, `sale price` and a `style`.

Each piece of jewelry can be made from one or more `material`, e.g. white gold and diamond. The **same material can be used to make many pieces of jewelry**. The *materials used** and **their amount** for each piece must be recorded in the database.

Materials are described by `material code`, `title` and `feature`. **A material can be a mixture of other materials**. Then it is necessary to record the composition of the material including the `percentage` of each mixed material.
The **same material can be used to make many kinds of mixtures**.

For each piece of jewelry it is necessary to record the `artist` who created the piece of art. Information about artists is to be recorded in the database. It includes `artist ID`, `name`, `address` and `phone number`. One artist can create many pieces of jewelry. **Each piece of jewelry can be only made by one artist**.

Comment: What was your wrong answer, and what was wrong with it?